# Замена старой строки на новую Python

Tags: python, строки, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть файл `sample.txt` в нем хранится набор строчек:

```
1  
12  
123
```

Программа должна на месте старой строчки (line) вставить новую (new_line), отредактированную.
Пример того, как файл `sample.txt` должен измениться:

```
1  
21  
321
```

И того, как он изменяется сейчас:

```
1  
12  
1231  
21  
321
```

Как сделать, чтобы программа удаляла прошлую строчку и ставила новую на ее место?

Мне не так важно, через какой алгоритм проходит строка, главное понять, каким образом можно одну строку заменить на измененную версию этой строки.

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'a+')
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
for line in lines:
    line_splitted = list(''.join(line))
    new_line_splitted = [0]*len(line)
    for letter in range(len(line)):
        new_line_splitted[letter] = line_splitted[len(line)-letter-1]
    new_line = ''.join(new_line_splitted)
    f.write(new_line + '\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

В строке `f = open('sample.txt', 'a+')` `a+` означает что файл открыт для чтения и добавления, то есть все что вы пишите в файл, добавляется в его конец, старое содержимое файла остается. Используйте `'r+'`, для того чтобы открыть файл для чтения и записи в начало, перезаписывая его содержимое.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуясь советом @pinguin, решил проблему таким способом:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
f = open('sample.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
    line_splitted = list(''.join(line))
    new_line_splitted = [0]*len(line)
    for letter in range(len(line)):
        new_line_splitted[letter] = line_splitted[len(line)-letter-1]
    new_line = ''.join(new_line_splitted)
    f.write(new_line + '\n')
f.close()
```